# How to switch between UI implementations in run-time?

Tags: gwt

I'm developing an application using GWT 2.6.

Now I have a task to implement a functionality to switch between simple/expert modes (of view) at run-time. It means to show a simplified version of view which may contain another widgets.
But the problem is that all the views in most cases are "static" and defined as singletons (using GIN).

Is it possible to implement this using only GWT and what should I use to make it?.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways that this can be done. A couple of ideas that spring to mind:

Option 1.

Instead of using GIN to inject the view, inject a view provider (`com.google.inject.Provider`). This can be used by the code that builds the view (the activity?) to get the view. The implementation of the view provider can then return an implementation of the view for the relevant mode, simple or expert. For example,

```
@Inject
public ComposeMessageActivity(Provider<ComposeMessageView> viewProvider, ...) { ... }

@Override
public final void start(final AcceptsOneWidget panel, final EventBus eventBus) {
    view = viewProvider.get();
```

Option 2.

Use [deferred binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html). This is not so dynamic but has the advantage a simple implementation will be a smaller download than an expert implementation. There is a project, [gwt-seminar](https://github.com/ashtonthomas/gwt-seminar), on github that shows this in practice that has mobile and desktop versions.

Comment: I use activity. Will try providers.